Circuit that turns two LEDs off/on depending on switch
I have been trying to solve this for the last couple of days and no matter what I do, green LED always receives some current.
What I would like to happen is when the switch is closed, turn on just the green LED(this works), and when the switch is open turn on just the red LED(this is my problem). The circuit below always has a green LED on.
I do see that when the switch is open, Q2 remains in Active mode, but at the same time I'm not sure how could I eliminate current Ic to enter cut off.
Is this even posible with just resistors and NPN transistors, or do I need PNP and/or diodes to better direct the current?
This learning project (outside school) so I am trying to this using just basic electronic components.
Link to my circuit.


Have you considered using just a 2-way switch? Or do you have to use transistors?

https://tinyurl.com/27wu4xvs  or https://tinyurl.com/2ymcnjup

@PeterJennings I am specifically trying to bolster my understanding of how transistors work.

@G36 that's a great alternative! I tried to put together something similar before but I did not bias the transistors correctly. Your design is preferable since it would require one less transistor to squeeze in.

@sgp667 How transistors work and how to make two alternating LEDs light up are sort of not very related. The circuit could use many different kinds of transistors or you could use a simple logic IC if you just want a minimalistic circuit with say one IC than how to use a handful of transistors.

When the red is on, you have Vbe from Q3 and Vce from Q_no_number which seems to be enough to turn Q2 on in the simulator.
Swapping the green LED and its resistor raises the emitter voltage of Q2 by 2 or 3 V when on, so it requires more to turn on.
Falstad Simulation


From another thread, here is a non-standard approach that works very well.  SW1 can be replaced with a small n-channel MOSFET such as a 2N7000, or a small NPN transistor with a base resistor.
When the switch is open, current goes through the only available path, R4, D7, and D8.  When the switch is closed, a current path goes through D6.  Because the voltage drop across D6, called its forward voltage or Vf, is less than the combined Vf of D7 plus D8, D6 effectively "shorts out" the D7-D8 combo, starving away all of the current available through R4.  Thus, D6 is on and D7 is off.


I can't believe someone is actually using my idea from the 80s!

Actually (ahem), from the 70's.  I've used it around six times over the decades, both personally and professionally.  I think this is one of those circuits that many people "discover" independently.  I got the idea while working on a diode video switch for a TV station routing switcher.

Do you have any proof of that? I have a patent from 1983.

That is not the same circuit.  It has two driver transistors configured such that only one can be on at a time.  That is not the same current-starving principle.

No proof.  Worked my way through school on the night shift.  Bored and puttering around with circuits.  Much later, I built red/green LED status indicators for my garage doors that use this idea.  For that circuit I replaced R4 with a true constant-current source.  This yields more even brightness between the two LEDs.

It is the same, but it is a more sophisticated analog version with two LEDs that connect in parallel (one for positive and the other for negative input voltage) to the main one and turn it off. I just found this document. Your story sounds incredible, congratulations on your circuit enthusiasm!

Nice story!  || Thunkings: D8 is notionally not needed if Vfs vary enough. Conversely, if one diode is not enough more can be used. This would allow LEDs of the same colour or swapping red and green. Adding series R in one or both paths allows balancing brightness without a current source.

Nope.  The circuit works only if the sharpness of a diode's conduction "knee" acts as a comparator.  A resistor in either branch softens the knee and leads to partial conduction such that both diodes are partially visible at the same time.

Also, because the Vf curve of an LED already has a curve and a slope, the Vf's of the two LEDs have to be several tenth's of a volt apart or you again get dual partial visibility.  Typical cheap Red (1.8 V) and green (2.0 V) Vf's are too close together; hence the additional diode.

It should be obvious that one of the LEDs can be controlled directly by the switch. For the other LED, you need a simple inverter circuit. The simplest is to use a transistor to short it out.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Here's another few ways of doing it. In the top circuit R1 is optional in a breadboard, it just reduces the leakage in the transistors. The switch is not called upon to switch the LED current, rather just the base current. Q1 drives the green LED (high = ON) and Q2/Q3 drive the red LED (low or open = OFF).
The second circuit uses a Darlington configuration to get high current gain. That allows the current for the red LED driver to be very low, so with a 200kΩ base resistor and a 10kΩ resistor across the green LED it will have only around 250mV across it  and it will not turn on. Certainly R7 could be much higher and it will still work (1V or more would be okay) but if you leave out R7, the green LED will glow faintly (or not so faintly, depending on how good the LED is).


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Both circuits draw only slightly more than the current of a single LED. The circuit can be further simplified by shorting out the LED with a transistor, which doubles the current in one state, as Dave shows.

It's also possible to use a single transistor in place of the Darlington with a bit sharper pencil on the resistor values:

simulate this circuit


Basic idea
If two voltage-stabilizing nonlinear elements (e.g., diodes) with different threshold voltages are connected in parallel, the current will be diverted through the element with the lower threshold voltage. This phenomenon can be utilized to switch two LEDs with a simple SPST switch (e.g., NPN transistor).
Implementation
This allows us to create the simplest possible circuit for controlling two LEDs with different (e.g., 2 and 2.5 V) threshold voltages. In fact, there is no circuit because apart from the existing two LEDs, a current-limiting resistor, and a switch, there is nothing else.
Operation
SW OFF
Initially, the switch is open. The current flows through the LED 2 with the higher voltage.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
SW ON
Then the switch closes and connects the LED 1 with the lower voltage in parallel to LED 2. The current diverts through LED 1 and LED 2 turns off.

simulate this circuit

Based on TINA-TI simulation if the switch is open:

The collector-Emitter current (RED LED transistor) is almost zero and its based voltages is also not enough to make the transistor on, but the the collector-Emitter current(Green LED transistor) is 17mA, so the Green LED is ON:

If the switch is closed, the green LED should be On:


So let me take you through how to analyze the problem before solving it.
As you can see this is a digital 1,0 type problem; the first thing you can do here is draw a truth table (doesn't matter how simple the problem is, just do it)
Let us assume that 5V is high(1) and 0V is low(0);
When switch is closed the voltage on its other side is 1 and when it is open the voltage is 0;



INPUT
GREEN
RED




1
1
0


0
0
1



Now see that the function for green is the exact same as that for the input; so the input can just drive the green LED without any modifications(or if you want you can buffer the input to drive the Green LED; I'm going to not use the buffer as an LED draws very very little amount of current)
Also notice the the RED is just the input but inverted; Now how does a BJT inverter look:

Image source: Presentation from professor at my college (not public)
This is a very basic form of inverter; This can be modified to bias the BJT and add stability resistors at the Emitter to appropriately control the gain.
This is a circuit that I designed to solve your problem:

[Please don't use the capacitor for a switch as it won't work for DC as in the case for a switch]
Use the Pulse input as a replacement for the switch flipping between 1 and 0;
The 4k and 1k resistors are just for biasing the BJT; you can choose your own values for your BJT spice models and even use different biasing techniques; it doesn't matter;
All that matters is that it is an inverter circuit;
Also as prove that this works the simulation graphs:

Notice that the Green LED follows the exact pattern as the switch voltage and the Red LED follows the exact opposite pattern.
Hope this helps.

You don't really want that capacitor there. It will work at 5kHz as you've shown but won't work at DC (i.e. when using a switch).

Hi, thanks for noticing. You're absolutely correct, I put the cap there as a force of habit from audio electronics. I'll edit the answer.

This is a digital electronics problem since it is based on two states, 1 and 0.
You could use something like this:
LINK to the circuit

Q1 drives the green LED based on the input received from the switch -> if the switch is closed the LED turns on.
Q2 works as an inverter (NOT gate) -> if a signal is applied to the Q2's base, current flows from C to E directly to ground and no current goes to Q3's base. If no signal is applied, no current can flow from C to E and all the current goes to Q3's base through the resistor R3, thus turning on the red LED.
This way, instead of just LEDs, you could also control more power hungry devices such as heaters, power LEDs, motors and so on.
As a side note, the resistors values are indicative and need to be chosen based on the application.
